# How to create or convert private key in Unix/Linux in .ppk format which can be used in Windows PuTTY?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty

Is it possible to create or convert keys in Linux into .ppk format which can be used in PuTTY in Windows?

Without downloading any additional software like `puttygen`, possibly using standard tools like `ssh-keygen`.

To be more specific, the `.ppk` format with `ssh-2 protocol` and `bytes=2048`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `ssh-keygen` does not support the PuTTY key format. In both operating systems, you will need PuTTYgen.

- On Windows, use PuTTYgen's "Import OpenSSH key" command.
- On Linux, `puttygen input.key -o output.ppk`.

The format is documented in [sshpubk.c](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/sshpubk.c?view=markup):377 if you want to write your own program.